# Error when trying to cycle through Autofiltered Cells using vba

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm using the below code to remove invalid instances of text, in this case statements starting with colons. I know all of the steps I need to take, but I'm having issues after Autofitering. I've tried iterating through the visible cells using

```
for x=1 to currentFilter.rows.count
```

and

```
for each x in currentFilter.rows
```

But regardless of how I've tried I keep receiving some sort of error when trying to get rid of the the first character (the colon) by using (basic gist):

```
Cell Value = Right(Cell Value, Len(Cell Value) - InStr(Cell Value, ",", vbTextCompare))
```

My full code is as follows:

```
Sub PRTCheck()
    'Column AN is Production Time & Column AP is Rush Time
    Dim endRange As Integer, ShipandRush As Range, CommaColons As Collection, cell, i

    endRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ShipandRush = Union(ActiveSheet.Range("AN2:AN" & endRange), ActiveSheet.Range("AP2:AP" & endRange))

    ShipandRush.NumberFormat = "@"
    Set CommaColons = FindAllMatches(ShipandRush, ",:")
    If Not CommaColons Is Nothing Then
        Dim times() As String
        For Each cell In CommaColons
            times = Split(cell.Value, ",")
            For i = LBound(times) To UBound(times)
                If InStr(times(i), ":") = 1 Then times(i) = ""
            Next
            cell.Value = Join(times, ",")
            Do While InStr(cell.Value, ",,") <> 0
                cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ",,", ",", vbTextCompare)
            Loop
            If InStr(cell.Value, ",") = 1 Then
                cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
            End If
            If InStr(Len(cell.Value), cell.Value, ",") = Len(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    Set ShipandRush = ActiveSheet.Range("AN1:AN" & endRange)
    Dim currentFilter As Range, r
    ShipandRush.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=":*" 'Starts with colon
    Set currentFilter = ShipandRush.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If currentFilter.Rows.count > 0 Then
        For r = 1 To currentFilter.Rows.count
        '-------Error occurs on the next line-------
            currentFilter.Cells(r).Value = Right(currentFilter.Cells(r).Value, Len(currentFilter.Cells(r).Value) - InStr(currentFilter.Cells(r).Value, ",", vbTextCompare))
        Next
    End If
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End Sub

'Custom find and replace that circumvents 255 character find limitation
Function FindAllMatches(rng As Range, txt As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String, txtSrch As String
    Dim IsLong As Boolean

    IsLong = Len(txt) > 250
    txtSrch = IIf(IsLong, Left(txt, 250), txt)

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=txtSrch, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
    Do While Not f Is Nothing
        If f.Address(False, False) = addr Then Exit Do
        If Len(addr) = 0 Then addr = f.Address(False, False)
    'check for the *full* value (case-insensitive)
        If InStr(1, f.Value, txt, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(After:=f)
    Loop
    Set FindAllMatches = rv
End Function
```

**My Question:**

What am I doing wrong? How can I iterate through each value in the visible cells and perform the formula I noted above successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really only dealing with a single column but I will try to stick with your method of looping through the rows instead of the cells which in this instance are essentially the same thing (although [Range.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) is not the same thing as [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)).

Discontiguous ranges need to be cycled through by their [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) first and then the [Range.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) property within each area.

```
dim a as long, r as long
with currentFilter
    If .Rows.count > 0 Then
        for a = 1 to .Areas.count
            For r = 1 To .Areas(a).Rows.count
                .Areas(a).Rows(r).Cells(1).Value = _
                   Right(.Areas(a).Rows(r).Cells(1).Value, _
                         Len(.Areas(a).Rows(r).Cells(1).Value) - _
                         InStr(1, .Areas(a).Rows(r).Cells(1).Value, ","))
            Next r
        Next a
    End If
end with
```

It may be simpler to just use a For Each ... Next.

```
dim cfr as range
with currentFilter
    for each cfr in .Cells
        cfr = Right(cfr.Value, Len(cfr.Value) - InStr(1, cfr.Value, ","))
    Next cfr
end with
```

Comment: Ahh, my issue was using the for each loop with the rows instead of cells as you show the for each loop in your second snippet of code. And I'm actually doing this for two columns (AP & AN), but I only showed the first instance of this code. I wasn't certain that Autofilter would work for noncontiguous areas (I thought I read that in the msdn documentation). I figured I was just going to mimic the formula I was having issues with. Do you have any suggestions of how to cover both columns at once instead of doing them separately or should I stick with duplicating that code?

Comment: **ShipandRush** is only column AN:AN and that is what you use to set currentFilter to (e.g. ShipandRush.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) without resizing I might add). This is why I like working with .CurrentRegion; it makes extents easier to follow. But yes, you can only loop through the rows within a contiguous Area. You need to loop through each area and then the rows within each area. You might try looping through the .Cells in AN:AN and simply cfr.OffSet(0, 2) to get to column AP. Offset can go outside of its own confined column as long as you are not trying to go off the ws.

Comment: Why should I use resizing in this instance (and how)? From what you've described I believe I'll have no choice but to do these two actions separately since I can Autofilter noncontiguous columns. The reason I have to do it separately is because I'll have to reset the filter to filter for all cells beginning with a colon in column AP

Comment: Maybe you could loop it and union the two results. I dunno. You are talking about something you have not discussed in your question.